# Show person list based on group selection list in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm pretty new in django/ Python and any help will be appreciated

I'm trying to populate a list of person based on click on another list (Group)

Model:

```
class Grupo(models.Model):
    Nome = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

View

```
class GruposListView(ListView):
    model = Grupo
    template_name = 'reports/relatorio_form.html'
    context_object_name = 'Grupo'
```

HTML

```html
    <h4 class="mb-3">Select a group:</h4>
    <select id="Group" name="Group" size="5">
        {% for Grupo in Grupo %}
        <option value="Grupo">{{Grupo.Nome}}</option>
       {% endfor %}
    </select><br><br>
```

[Here the result on the first list:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7yhd.png)

Comment: So what is the problem? Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: Sorry about that, it's my very first post here. 

This code isn't working because doesn't have the proper code... I need to know how to do that... i need to populate a second list(members) when clicking on one item from the first list(group)

Comment: I don't know much about Django, but I know Python, and this line in your HTML `{% for Grupo in Grupo %}` is a problem. You can't create a temp variable with the same name as the collection variable. Just change the first `Grupo` to literally any other valid Python identifier and see what happens.

Comment: I changed it to : ```{% for a in Grupo %}```
It's fetching data from my database to the page normally , now I need to fetch the members to a new select list when I click on one item from groups item

Comment: Your select input options will all have the same value `Groupo` which doesn't differentiate the options. You could use`{{Grupo.pk}}` as it is unique enough to work.

Answer (score 0):

You needs rather some good tutorial instead of this answer.

HTML should have `<form>` and `<button>` to send selected group to server (ie. to other class `GroupDetailView`), and serve should get in as argument using

```
 re_path(r'^group/(?P<group_number>\d+)$', views.GroupDetailView.as_view(), name='group-detail'),
```

and

```
 class GroupDetailView(...):

    def group_detail_view(request, group_number):
```

and use it to get persons from selected group

```
    def group_detail_view(request, group_number):

        persons = Person.objects.get(group=group_number)
```

and generate page with these person.

```
    def group_detail_view(request, group_number):

        persons = Person.objects.get(group=group_number)

        return render(request, 'group_detail.html', context={'persons':  persons})
```

---

All based on tutorial [Django Tutorial Part 6: Generic list and detail views](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views)